# Is there always a solution $x$ to $x^x$ $=$ $a$ $\pmod p$ with $p$ prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, problem-solving

Is tnt following conjecture true:

There is always a solution $x$ to $x^x$ $=$ $a$ $\pmod p$ for any integer $a$ and prime $p$.

I was struggling with a problem recently to find the integer $x$ such that $x^x$ $=$ $a$ $\pmod p$ assuming my conjecture is true. For example, how would one easily solve $x^x$ $=$ $15$ $\pmod {59}$ not using brute force hopefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)=1$ and $a$ is any unit mod $n$ then solving the system

$$\begin{cases} x\equiv a \mod n \\ x\equiv 1 \mod \varphi(n)\end{cases} $$

for $x$ (using Sun-Zi aka [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)) then $x$ is a solution to $x^x\equiv a$ mod $n$.

Comment: So my conjecture is an true for square-free moduli $p$?

Comment: @J.Linne It's probably true beyond that even, but this argument is valid whenever $n$ is squarefree and $p\nmid (q-1)$ for all prime divisors $p,q\mid n$.

Comment: In order to have $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)=1$, it's necessary but not sufficient that $n$ is square-free.

Comment: @arctictern $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)=1$ for $n\ge 2$, $n\in\mathbb Z$ is true if and only if $n$ is square-free and the following implication is true ($p,q$ are prime): $p,q\mid n\implies p\nmid q-1$. It's the same condition you mentioned, but notice that no other $n\ge 2$ can satisfy $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)=1$ (you had doubts if it's true beyond that, but it's not).

Comment: If $p^2\mid n$ for some prime $p$, then $p\mid \varphi(n)$, so $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)>1$. Therefore $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)=1\implies n$ is square-free (I'm adding this comment for others to see).

Comment: @user236182 When I said "it's probably true beyond that even," I meant it's probably true that there are solutions to $x^x\equiv a$ mod $n$ beyond even squarefree $n$. If anybody wishes to look them up, the numbers $n$ coprime to $\varphi(n)$ are called "cyclicity-forcing" (because they are precisely the $n$ for which $|G|=n$ implies $G$ is cyclic in the context of finite groups).

Comment: @arctictern I see. I misunderstood it. If $n\ge 2$, $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)=1$, then $x^x\equiv a\pmod{n}$ is solvable for all $a\in\mathbb Z$, but it's not true if $\gcd(\varphi(n),n)>1$. E.g., if $p^2\mid n$ for some prime $p$, then $x^x\equiv p\pmod{n}$ isn't solvable.

Comment: @user236182 Indeed, so it'd be natural to (say) restrict to $a$ being a unit mod $n$ if $n$ is not coprime to $\varphi(n)$. There are solutions to $x^x\equiv a$ mod $n$ beyond cyclicity-forcing $n$, but there aren't always solutions.

Answer (score 6):

We may assume  $a$ coprime to $p$.  Let $b$ be a primitive root mod $p$.  Then
$(b + kp)^{b+kp} \equiv b^{b+kp} \equiv b^{b+k} \equiv a \mod p$ for suitable $k$.

Comment: I think that normally a primitive root mod $n$ is denoted by the letter $g$, but it doesn't matter here of course.

Comment: @user236182 I really don't think that's a rule.  But use whatever letter you want.